# Extract a patch from an image given patch center and patch scale

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image of size `1200 x 800`.

I want to extract a *square patch* from this image given a *patch center* `500, 450` and a *patch scale* `23%` of the smaller dimension of the image.

Is there any function in `opencv`, `skimage` or any library that allows me to do it in `python`?

Comment: Yes.  This is a simple and common operation and you can do this in `OpenCV`, `skimage`, and also `PIL` and pure `numpy`.  You should pick the library you want to use (probably based on other criteria since they can all do this), try to do it with whatever tool you pick, and then ask a question if you have trouble with that (which you probably won't).

Comment: Hint: 23% of smaller dimension is 0.23 * 800.. Rectangle top-left corner is (center_x - width/2, center_y - height/2). For square patch width = height.

Comment: Might be a simple question, but doesn't deserve a negative vote...

Answer (score 5):

Using OpenCV python, you can do this:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load the image
image = cv2.imread('path/to/your_image.jpg')

# define some values
patch_center = np.array([500, 450])
patch_scale = 0.23

# calc patch position and extract the patch
smaller_dim = np.min(image.shape[0:2])
patch_size = int(patch_scale * smaller_dim)
patch_x = int(patch_center[0] - patch_size / 2.)
patch_y = int(patch_center[1] - patch_size / 2.)
patch_image = image[patch_x:patch_x+patch_size, patch_y:patch_y+patch_size]

# show image and patch
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('patch_image', patch_image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Notice that this was done step-by-step just to be easier to understand. You can do many of these steps directly.